# True or false: Every real homogeneous linear system of equation which has more than one solution has infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

*This is a task from a test exam you can find here (in German):
http://docdro.id/QRtdXkM*

> Is the following statement true or false?
>
> Every real homogeneous linear system of equation that has more than
>   one solution, has infinite solutions.

I think the statement is true because a linear system of equations can only have either one solution, no solution or infinite solutions. This statement clearly says "more than one solution $\rightarrow$ infinite solutions" which is true.

Is it really correct like that or there is some special case which can make this statement false?

Comment: The statement is correct but you need to prove it mathematically. How do you know that " a linear system of equations can only have either one solution, no solution or infinite solutions"?

Comment: The statement is wrong because no linear equation has an infinite solution.

Comment: @CarstenS: The question is clearly using "infinite" as a numeral, essentially as a shorthand for "an infinite number of". Whether you consider such use of the word "infinite" to be proper English or not, it's certainly clear enough in context. If the question had instead said "... has five solutions", you wouldn't object on the basis that 5 is not necessarily a solution, would you?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen the thing is that *five* is a numeral and *infinite* is not. Exact language is important. The OP has already received helpful answers, so my comment will not harm him, but maybe he will think for a moment about why the original problem said “unendlich viele” and not “unendliche”.

Comment: And another remark to the OP: Would the answer have been different if the question had not explicitly said *real*?

Comment: @CarstenS I think the statement would be false because if we take some number range where zero is excluded then we could get no solutions, as zero is not defined. But it sounds paradoxical already to use a number range where zero is excluded and speak of a homogeneous linear system of equation. And if we didn't use the word "real" we couldn't get infinite solutions, too.(?)

Comment: @CarstenS: "between 5 and 7" is also not a numeral. Would you therefore have objected if he had written "between 5 and 9 solutions"? And since we are speaking of the cardinality of the set of solutions, the numbers in question are the cardinal numbers, and there indeed exist infinite cardinal numbers (although not a single numeral "infinite", just as there is not a single numeral "between 5 and 9"). Indeed, in the case of more than one solution, there are exactly $\mathfrak c$ solutions, where $\mathfrak c$ is the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: To be honest, I still don't see why my title has been critisized and what you guys are talking about. Maybe someone can explain me easier what the issue is? I'm trying to understand but I don't.

Comment: @cnmesr: You made a simple English language error, writing "infinite solutions" where you clearly meant "infinitely many solutions". The rest of the discussion is simply whether this is a serious problem (as Carsten S seems to claim) or rather nitpicking (as Ilmari Karonen and myself think).

Comment: Interpolationg between 2 solutions gives another solution.

Comment: @cnesr, when I suggested to consider alternatives to the real numbers I had meant that we could be working over a different *field*. What is always true is that if there more one solution, then the solutions form a subspace of dimension at least 1. If the field is infinite then so is that subspace, but I saw on your practice exam that you also know about finite fields. The other remark was indeed about “unendlich viele Lösungen” vs “unendliche Lösungen”. Maybe you would not have mixed them up in German. Good luck with the exam, in case that one is coming up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed, this is even true for non-homogeneous linear systems. Consider the system $Ax=b$, and assume $x_0$ and $x_1$ are solutions. Then for any $x_\lambda = (1-\lambda)x_0+\lambda x_1$ you get
$$Ax_\lambda = A((1-\lambda)x_0 + \lambda x_1) = (1-\lambda)A x_0 + \lambda A x_1 = (1-\lambda) b + \lambda b = b$$
Therefore $x_\lambda$ is also a solution, thus you get infinitely many (indeed even uncountably many) solutions.

The homogeneous system is just the special case for $b=0$. Since $x=0$ is always a solution of a homogeneous linear system, for those you can even write the condition as:

> If any real homogeneous linear system of equations has a non-zero solution, it has infinitely many.

Comment: The last sentence is very nice to know, surely also the rest of your answer, now I understood, thanks!

Comment: One more question came to my mind though. Can we also say that homogeneous linear system of equation are always solvable? We know they always have at least one solution; zero. They can also have infinite solutions. But they can never have no solution, right?

Comment: @cnsmer: note that the zerovector always forms a solution to a homogeneous system of equations. Therefore, you can only have either 1 (in case A is invertable) or infinitely many (in case A is singular) solutions.

Comment: @cnmesr The clam that there are infinitely many solutions is not true generally, e.g. if the coefficient field is a *finite* field such as $\,\Bbb Z_2 = $ integers mod $2$. Generally vector spaces are defined over any field of scalars.

Comment: @BillDubuque: But then it would not be a *real* homogeneous linear system of equations, would it?

Comment: @celtschk Right, that's why I wrote "generally", and mentioned the general definition of a vector space.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Well, if you want to be completely general, you can also get infinitely many solutions over $\mathbb Z_2$ by simply having an infinite-dimensional vector space. Of course if the vector space has only finitely many elements (finite dimensional vector space over finite field), there cannot be infinitely many solutions among them.

Comment: @celtschk Right, as I said, the statement is not true in general. The reason I emphasized that is because it is one place where students often make errors, so I though it worth mention.

Comment: I guess you can choose between 'true' and 'false', but what's the third row for?

Comment: @ClassicEndingMusic: I guess you refer to the exam linked in the question. It is labelled "weiß nicht" which is German for "don't know". According to the rules stated on the exam, if you cross the wrong answer, you get a point deducted, but if you cross "don't know" your points are not affected. The idea probably being to discourage guessing the answer.

Comment: @celtschk Yeah exactly that. They are sooo mean right.. :'(

Answer (score 5):

Hint: if the homogeneous system has two distinct solutions, then one of them, call it $v$, is nonzero. What can you say about $\alpha v$ for a scalar $\alpha$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes indeed this is true. The way that this is best seen is by noting that if a homogeneous system of equations has more than one solution, then the matrix corresponding to the system of equations, $A$, has a non-trivial kernel.

This means that $\exists \vec{v},\vec{u} \in \ker(A): A\vec{v} = 0$ and $A\vec{u} = 0$. Now it is worth noting that we can take any linear combination of these vectors $\lambda \vec{v} + \mu \vec{u}$ for $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and we have $A(\lambda \vec{v} + \mu \vec{u}) = \lambda A\vec{v} + \mu A\vec{u} = 0$, so $\lambda \vec{v} + \mu \vec{u}$ also solves this system of equations.

Therefore we have an infinite number of solutions if we have more than one unique solution.

Answer (score 2):

Every linear comination over $\mathbb{R}$ of two solutions of a homogeneous linear system will be solution to the homogeneous linear system. One of the solutions in necessarly not the zero vector and then it has infinte non trivial combinations which are solutions.
If you write it as a matrix, $A \in _{\mathbb{R}_{n \times m}}$, represents the homogeneous linear equation system, andfor the vectors $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $Aa=0,Ab=0$.

From that you get that for every $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, exists:

$A(\alpha a+\beta b)=\alpha Aa+\beta Ab=0$.